# Encapsulation, Inheritance and Polymorphis

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, encapsulation

### Please give me example of what this would look like. I am a bit confused and I have to do several sets of this. If somebody could give me a sample code I would really appreciate it.

variable is radius
Methods:
 A Circle class constructor with no parameters. This method first invokes the super class constructor with no parameters by the statement, super(); The method then assigns the radius variable a default value of 1.0.

A Circle class constructor with a newRadius parameter. This method first invokes the super class constructor with no parameters by the statement: super(); The method then assigns the value of newRadius to the radius variable if newRadius is greater than zero. Otherwise, it assigns radius the default value of 1.0.

A Circle class constructor with newX, newY, and newRadius parameters, in that order. This method first invokes the super class constructor with two parameters by the statement: super(newX, newY); The method then assigns the value of newRadius to the radius variable if newRadius is greater than zero. Otherwise, it assigns radius the default value of 1.0.

getRadius() – A double return-type method with no parameters. Returns the radius of this Circle.

setRadius() – A void return-type method with a newRadius parameter. This method assigns the value of newRadius to the radius variable if newRadius is greater than zero.Otherwise, it assigns radius the default value of 1.0.

getArea() – A double return-type method with no parameters. This method computes and returns the area of the Circle by the formula: radius * radius * 3.14159. toString() – A String return-type method with no parameters. 
This method returns a String containing the name of this class, Circle, the x and y coordinates and the radius of this Circle.

Comment: at least try some thing and bring your code then post if there is some errors.

Comment: Im not asking for answers, just an example of what this would look like.

Comment: Ive got a class called shape so far and this is what it looks like

 package phase1;


//shape calls children tri,cir,rec
public abstract class Shape {
   
   //variables
   private int x;
   private int y;
    
   public Shape () {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}
   
   public Shape (int newx, int newy ) {
  x = newx;
  y = newy;
   }
   
   //gets x
   public int getx () {
   return x;
   }
   
   //gets y
   public int gety () {
   return y;
   }
   
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public Class Circle{
    double radius;
    public Circle(){
        super();
        radius = 1.0;
    }
    public Circle(double newRadius){
        super();
        if(newRadius>0)
            radius = newRadius;
        else
            radius = 1.0;
    }
    public Circle(int newX, int newY, double newRadius){
        super(newX,newY);
        if(newRadius>0)
            radius = newRadius;
        else
            radius = 1.0;
    }
    public double getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }
    public void setRadius(double newRadius){
        if(newRadius>0)
            radius = newRadius;
        else
            radius = 1.0;
    }
}
```

this is the structure of your question implement functionality by your self.